# Unable to validate title of URL of a website

Tags: selenium-webdriver, title

I tried to validate the title of URL, the code have mentioned below show no error but gave wrong output. Please see my code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
String c;
c = driver.getTitle();
if (c!="Google")
System.out.println("True");
driver.close();
}
```

why output is `True`. however Title of the URL is `Google`

Comment: URLs do not have a title. Documents can, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/366348

> == tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object).
>
> .equals() tests for value equality (whether they are logically
>   "equal").

so correct code is `if (!c.equals("Google"))`

Comment: Correct answer. can u please explain why code of user who ask it is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking correct but why it show incorrect result unable to understand. Try this, it works correctly for me.

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
String c;
c = driver.getTitle();
System.out.println(c);
if (!c.equals("Google"))
{
System.out.println("True");
}
driver.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your code was pretty good enough to retrieve the title as `Google`. However, this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) points us to a couple of simple facts about `String` literals in `Java` as follows:

1. `==` tests should be used for reference equality (if they are the same object).
2. `.equals()` tests should be used for value equality (if they are literally equal).

Hence changing `if (c!="Google")` to `if (!c.equals("Google"))` should have solved your purpose.

### Getting Granular:

As we are comparing string literals, my take will be to get more granular and use `if (!c.contentEquals("Google"))` instead of `if (!c.equals("Google"))`.

### Solution:

Hence a proper solution to your problem will be to define the `if()` as follows:

```
    public class GooglePageTitle 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.google.com");
            String c;
            c = driver.getTitle();
            if (!c.contentEquals("Google"))
            System.out.println("True");
            driver.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here it's. you can't verify string data type with != operator. you should stick with manipulation functions.

```
 if (!c.contentEquals("Google"))
```